# How to stop a specific HTTP request from resolving in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to stop a request URL with a matching endpoint? Say for example, if I know that the request contains: "https://example.com", is it possible to stop that and only that request from resolving successfully?

I was digging through Stack Overflow threads and Google, and found about `window.stop()` and `AbortController` for `fetch()` but that doesn't help since I don't have a "Cancel" button in my application. I need to stop an HTTP request from resolving when a user clicks on another element and the only way to accomplish this is by stopping the specific HTTP request from resolving successfully.

Is this possible?

I can try both vanilla JavaScript and jQuery solutions.

Comment: you say that you don't have a cancel button, but you then say you want to cancel when the user clicks on another element. So there you have it, you should listen for clicks in these other elements and cancel the request. You have to find a way to hook the cancellation in an event. (AbortController for featch seems ok for your case)

Comment: To all of you, I'm sorry that I asked this question while finding another solution that has nothing to do with HTTP requests.

I decided to add a "dynamic" id attribute to the element and check if the element id value matches with the URL slug. If they match, some logic will fire, if they don't, then `return;` .The id attribute on the element changes on every click.